# What is 'n' column in the below output?

Tags: r

I have a code line in R as below

```
tele1%>%mutate(dec=ntile(totmrc_Mean,n=10))%>%count(churn,dec)%>%filter(churn==1)->dat2
```

Output is as below

```
churn   dec n
1       1   1831
1       1   2292
1       1   1492
1       1   1935
1       1   2048
1       1   368
1       1   1585
1       1   1722
1       1   1306
1       1   1211
1      NA   69
```

what is the column 'n' in the output and how it is calculated

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272

Comment: This has been asked very recently with the same verbatim code, but by a different user. Did you delete your previous user and create a new account, or is this for a class? Please go to where-ever you got this code and ask them, as it appears they have given you no indication of how to look for help. (You should start by typing in `?count` and reading, as it explains what is going on.)

Comment: For the record, I found one such source for this line of code: https://github.com/agrawalmanisha/Telecom_Churn/blob/master/Telecom_Churn.R

Comment: Have you posted the same question under a new alias? Are you in the same college or company? This question was asked and answered earlier today.

Comment: The question has annoyingly been deleted as I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It gets added by `count`*:

```
dplyr::count(mtcars,cyl)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl     n
  <dbl> <int>
1  4.00    11
2  6.00     7
3  8.00    14
```

*: `count` is actually short for `group_by() + tally()` and it is in `tally` that `n` is defined. If an `n` already exists in your data, then it will be named `nn` as specified in `dplyr:::n_name`, and so forth if `nn` is also already in the data, etc.